# How to play a WAV file loaded from Assets folder in Android?

Tags: java, android, media-player

I'm trying to play a `.wav` audio in Android from `assets` folder.

The problem is that there is no error but the audio isn't playing.

Here's my code

```
AssetFileDescriptor afd = null;
try {
   afd = getAssets().openFd("success.wav");
   player = new MediaPlayer();
                        player.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
   player.setLooping(false);
   player.prepare();
   player.start();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is ok, i checked, its working.

1. Please ensure the `\assets` folder is placed
   correctly(`\app\src\main\assets`)
2. Check your device volume level.
3. Play `success.wav` in PC media player and ensure it is audible.

**Note:**
Using device volume controls:

```
setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
```

If your app is media related, use setVolumeControlStream API at your onResume() of activity or fragment and use device volume hard keys to increase/decrease volume. This set the application to only modify stream_music volume /media volume, otherwise it will modifiy ring volume.
Ref:https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones

Comment: The audio is working fine on PC, the volume is on top level, and I'm already working with assets folder is other activities so it's in the right place.

Comment: I'm sorry for not checking again, but I don't know why in the application the volume sets to none always, problem fixed thank you.

Comment: Welcome, if you want to change the STREAM_MUSIC volume from your activity when pressing the device volume  hard keys, check this setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC)  at https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/volume-and-earphones

Comment: setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC) sets the application to only modify stream_music volume /media volume, otherwise it modified ring volume. JFYI.

Answer (score 1):

Did You try this?

```
 MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = null;

    public void playSound(final Context context, final String fileName) {
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = context.getAssets().openFd(fileName);
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            afd.close();
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
        } catch (final Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        mediaPlayer.start();
    }
}
```

Comment: It didn't play as well. I should mention that the wav file is short (like 1-2 seconds), I am telling you this because I've read that for short audio I should use Sound pool

Comment: Thank you man for your code, it's working like charm. Even mine was working , the problem was in volume.